# How do I change the author column in back-end to display USERNAME not display name?

Tags: php, wordpress

In the Admin area of Wordpress, how would I change the output of the author column to display an Authors username, rather than the display name?

For example a user's display name (`get_author_name`) can be:

```
Jane Smith 
John Doe
```

But we want to be viewing their assigned username (get_userdata()->user_login) instead:

janesmith
johndoe

This would take place on the `/wp-admin/edit.php` url

I am aware of `manage_posts_columns()`, but I think what I need is a filter, as I am only changing the output? Where to hook into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'the_author' hook to display the username. Paste the following code in the functions.php of your theme file.

```
function change_the_author( $name ) {
     $name = get_the_author_meta( 'user_login' );
     return $name;

}
add_filter( 'the_author', 'change_the_author', 10, 1);
```

Reference:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_author/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/

Comment: Perfect, although I added is_admin so make it only apply to the back end as needed